# Overriding AppDelegate init

Tags: ios

Is it wrong to override this method to fire up some framework configurations instead of doing it the usual way, in `will/didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

I've never even thought of it having an `init` method until now, but I just saw a question on SO which had this bit of code (unrelated to the question), and was wondering if it's a bad idea (and why).

Haven't really managed to find anything related to this question, hopefully it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I've been doing just that for many years. Works fine.

Comment: @rmaddy this sounds good. Does it impact the total time limit of 20 seconds to open an app?

Comment: Probably. Whatever you do should be quick or put on a background queue.

Comment: I suppose it impacts the time limit in the same way putting the code in `will/DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` would. The only (sometimes big) advantage I can think of right now is a better code structure.